# blank page on the the website in prestashop Uncaught exception 'Shop not found'

Tags: php, prestashop

My site was working fine till last week. Both the admin and front end was working fine, both locally and on the server. On the local server in my system, the site is still working fine. I am facing a problem on the live server

From the past few days, I have been getting a blank page online at the server.

Upon checking the error log I found the following error::

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopException' with message 
'Shop not found' in /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/shop/Shop.php:369 
Stack trace: #0 /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/config/config.inc.php(91): 
ShopCore::initialize() #1 /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/index.php(27): 
require('/home/thebaker/...')
 #2 {main} thrown in /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/shop/Shop.php 
on line 369
```

Admin panel is showing the following error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Language.php on line 671
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Language.php on line 671
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Tab.php on line 261
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Tab.php on line 208
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Profile.php on line 145
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/controller/AdminController.php
>   on line 1250
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Tab.php on line 231
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/Language.php on line 671
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/module/Module.php on line 969
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/module/Module.php on line 164
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/modules/watermark/watermark.php on
>   line 55
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/thebaker/public_html/demo/classes/module/Module.php on line 1115

I have tried implementing solutions like changing the permissions at the server(from 755 to 775) and also uploading a new .htaccess file but I am unable to solve this issue.

Can someone please help me in this. I am newbie at prestashop and am not into core development. This is my first attempt in building a website in Prestashop

Thanks so much...

Note : My website is built on **Prestashop 1.5.4.1**

Comment: Is it normal that you're inside a "demo" folder in your live server?

Comment: the site is not yet live. Hence it is in the "demo" folder.

Answer (score 1):

'Shop not found' - it can appear, if you forgot to upgrade db to Prestashop 1.5.xx after 1.4.xx.

Or you just restore very old DB (v1.4) from you backup.

Comment: Have not upgraded the prestashop version as the website has been  originally built on Prestashop 1.5.4.1 itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 1.4.11 -> 1.6.0

I've renamed the /override folder and the eshop started working again.

One of the older overrides was probably conflicting with the new classes.

Temporarily remove all old overrides and see if that helps.